# Regular expression with only one decimal position

Tags: regex, ipad, ios5

I want to validate a text string for a specific value:

1. All numeric except for a decimal.
2. The decimal cannot be the first or last character.
3. It can have any number of digits but only one decimal.

I am trying to find a reference that will describe the mask below as it does not fit my needs.

```
NSString *myRegex = @"^\\d+(?:[:](?:[0-5]?\\d)|\\.\\d)$";
```

Please lead me to the documentation that describes the above characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

How about:

```
NSString *myRegex = @"^\d+(\.\d+)?$";
```

Have you thought about commas, dollar signs, negative or positive signs?  If those are allowed then you should probably try to parse the string as a number using an iOS library method.

Comment: Can you direct me to the documentation that explains the expression

Comment: I did.  Have a look at the site I linked in my answer: http://www.regular-expressions.info/